# Find the index number of where a variable fits between in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Category': ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],
    'Value':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
    }
           
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

I then have a defined variable of a number that may change:
e.g `val = 45`

How do i search the dataframe column `Value` and return the index number of the row where `val`  would fit.

Expected value would be:

for `val = 45` the index i would like returned is 4

for `val = 22` the index i would like returned is 2

for `val = 60` the index i would like returned is 6 (would go after if it has a match)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `argmax`

```
(df['Value'] > 45).argmax() # 4
(df['Value'] > 22).argmax() # 2
(df['Value'] > 60).argmax() # 6
```

This assumes `'Value'` is sorted, but it works because the result of the comparison is a boolean array, so it is returning the index of the *first* `True` value.

### Edit

To be more rigorous, we can support numbers that are greater than any value in the array:

```
tmp = (df['Value'] > 100)
index = tmp.argmax() if tmp.any() else len(df)
```

In this case, we correctly get 7 whereas using `argmax` alone returns 0.

If you **hate** the extra one line, it looks like you can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) in Python 3.8+:

```
 tmp.argmax() if (tmp := (df['Value'] > 100)).any() else len(df)
```

### Correction

Thanks to @Bill, I can see that `argmax` is in fact deprecated, and `idxmax` is the correct way to go:

```
(df['Value'] > 45).idxmax() # 4
(df['Value'] > 22).idxmax() # 2
(df['Value'] > 60).idxmax() # 6

tmp.idxmax() if (tmp := (df['Value'] > 100)).any() else len(df) # 7
tmp.idxmax() if (tmp := (df['Value'] > 22)).any() else len(df) # 2
```

Comment: [`argmax` is deprecated since version 0.21.0.](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html).  Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) instead

Comment: An alternate and _possibly_ more readable syntax would be `df['Value'].gt(45).idxmax()`, instead of `(df['Value'] > 45).idxmax()`

Comment: Thank you very much. Have learnt a bit here! appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of ways to do this, but this also works exactly as you would like and is identical to using argmax.

```
val = 45

min(df.loc[(df['Value'] > val)].index)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. this also worked for me (as did the one above which i accepted as the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html)

```
df.Value.searchsorted([45,22,60], side='right')
```

Output

```
array([4, 2, 6])
```